# Insulation of SiC Diode

Tags: diodes, clearance, creepage, insulation-voltage

I am reading about creepage distance and clearance and came across a T0-247-3 SiC diode ([IDW20G120C5B](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IDW20G120C5B-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d461464245d3014695635f956a3f)). This diode is rated for 1.2kV which would mean that it won't break down at let's say 800V, which is fine. But I checked the physical distance between the anode and cathode pin and it is 2.5 mm, which as per Pollution degree2 material group 4 (I chose this category as found most of sensors following this), can sustain only 250V. Isn't this contradictory? Or what am I missing

Comment: related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188416/how-can-a-high-voltage-transistor-be-in-such-small-packaging/188452

Comment: Welcome to the world of high voltage! Good silicon is available but capsules are hard to come by.

Answer (score 0):

This is not contradictory if you add some kind of compound to seal the legs.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you would put on the leads, and what requirements are needed to select the compound?